# How to precompile/fix CSS inconsistencies when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass

Essentially my CSS is running correctly on my local device, however, when I deployed to Heroku the stylings were off. Mainly on my `resumePage` you can see in the pictures that it is not fitting in the container it is located in and overflows into the `footerNav`.

How can I fix this error?

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K81gB.jpg) - Heroku App

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHIsQ.jpg) - Local Device

// Heroku URL
https://alexdelgado.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Can you confirm all of the styles are there? Are there any 404's in the network tab?

Comment: Yes, all the styles are there. And no, no 404's in the network tab. Only status 200.

Comment: Hmm. What's your Heroku url with it, without looking it's hard to tell. And there are no errors when you deploy to heroku?

Comment: https://alexdelgado.herokuapp.com/ - no errors when I deploy. And I'm compiling everything perfectly on the local side.

Comment: Should I ```yarn build``` before then push to Heroku?

Comment: Typically your deploy should run your build set.

Comment: I see the issue with your CSS, it's the height you have spec'd on your `resume_wrapper`. Quick fix would be to have `overflow-x: scroll` set. Not sure why you'd see the issue after deloying to heroku and not on your localhost unless you have the screen widths set differently.

Comment: FWIW, on my 24' monitor when I have the browser spanning full width, I don't see the issue.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. Most of my screen widths are set in the media queries as max-width? Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Rule of thumb is to start with your mobile styles first and use `min-width` in your media queries and go up. So for instance your smallest screen stuff would not have any media query wrapping it, then you'd start with say tablets at 768, etc, ...

Comment: @bgaynor78 thank you, I appreciate all your help this morning.